# Trying to create a image upload feature in app inventor using POSTFILE and PHP and PHP_Compat

Tags: php, android, app-inventor

Here is the POSTFILE code in App inventor:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gndlxibrg8f85b/uploadimage.jpg?dl=0

Here is the PHP script:

```
<?php

$ACCESSKEY="uhuh";

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');

if($_GET['p']==$ACCESSKEY){
  // this is the workaround for file_get_contents(...)
  require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/PHP_Compat/Compat/Function/file_get_contents.php');

  $data = php_compat_file_get_contents('php://input');

  $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/".$_GET['filename'];

  if (file_put_contents($filename,$data)) {
    if (filesize($filename) !=0) {

      echo "File transfer completed";

    } else {
      //header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
      echo "Error: File is empty.";
    }
  } else {
    //header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
    echo "Error: File transfer failed.";
  }
} else {

  //header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
  echo "Error: Access denied";     //reports if accesskey is wrong
}

?>
```

I am using PHP_Compat located here:
http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat/

When I tried using desktop emulator, it returns error "411: content length required".  But when i try using apk on the phone, after selecting image from phone and pressing UPLOAD the filename (of the right image) gets created on the server in right folder too, but the size is always zero and the script returns "error transfer failed".

Even rang GoDaddy and thought it might be due to some server or php setting but they could not help much.  I thought maybe changing the PHP variable upload_tmp_dir might help but cant do it.

I really need this work for my app so Hope someone can help.

Comment: We already talked about this in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/B0p0HNAs0yI/QGxMuIHezHIJ). If you get the message "file transfer failed", you can try the [answer from Q2 here](https://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php#q). GoDaddy is very restrictive about their settings, but probably you can find out what needs to be changed on the server together with their support. And as already said in the forum, **it would be nice to give appropriate credit to the author you "copied" the solution from** according to his [license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Comment: I didnt claim this to be my own work the script still has the comments with the appropriate credits in it!  Its just i didnt copy them into this post to minimise the post and make it easy reading..  I read your reply on the other forum and that may work as a workaround its not a solution.  If you pay loads of money for a fast unlimited space server you should be able to make use of the speed and space, otherwise yes i already knew about free hosts.  They are slow, unreliable and restricted space.  The script was taken from Purevida and written by taifun,  Im still left without a solution